# Clicking a specific element in a list of web elements works only half the time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read in a name from an excel file using openpyxl (into a variable name placeHolder) so I can iterate through a list of webelements and click the one that is equal to placeHolder. The reading in from excel works perfectly fine but the clicking ( specifically e.click() ) only works half of the time.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
browser.switch_to.frame("DialogWindow")
ele = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for e in ele:
            if e.text == placeHolder: #The variable being read in from and excel file using openpyxl
                try:
                    e.click() #only works sometimes
                except:
                    print("Element was not clicked")
                break

        time.sleep(2)
        browser.switch_to.default_content()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucDashboard_ucPortfolioContainer_ctl01_tblAccounts > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > a').click()
```

Comment: Could be anything from Selenium to the browser. You should probably log (using the logging module) the elements that are not working and try them in isolation.

Comment: What do you mean _does not work_? Any exceptions or simply no action? Elements can be hidden or disabled so that they are not clickable.

Comment: Thanks Charlie I will look into the logging module! and Würgspaß it just takes no action and then errors on the next line of code as that element is on a different page the first click redirects you to. I found a work around for now but am still curious as to why it didn't work 100% of the time.